# The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying use Expression and pass to query. But I have error - The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. I'm also used linqkit.dll with AsExpandable(), but but have the same error.

```
public List<Correct> GetCorrects(Expression<Func<Correct, bool?>> predicate)
{
    using (SystemsEntities context = new SystemsEntities())
    {
        var result = context.Corrects.Where(x => predicate == null);
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

I get the error stated above. What is failing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this:

```
var result = context.Corrects.Where(predicate);
```

instead of this:

```
var result = context.Corrects.Where(x => predicate == null);
```

`Where` expects argument of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, but you're trying to pass `Expression<Func<T, Expression<...>>` instead. This is valid compile-time construct, but at run-time LINQ provider fails, when it tries to translate `predicate` to SQL.

Also note, that you should change `Expression<Func<Correct, bool?>>` into `Expression<Func<Correct, bool>>`.